# Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

Tags: linux, vim, pipe, xargs

I am not an advanced linux user and I have a hard time wrapping my head around some new concepts.
I recently read about `xargs` command and wanted to test some examples. One of them confused me like hell.

The theory was this:
If I can start editing a non existent file in `vim` (with `vim someFile`) and create it only after it is edited (with `:qw`) then I could use `echo` and `xargs` to do the same job:

`echo "someFile" | xargs vim`

`xargs` will get the output of `echo` from `stdout` and will pass it as an argument to `vim`. It appears however this leads to the following error -

> Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

The strangest thing is that a second after the error is printed `vim` will open the file but when I save it and exit `vim` my terminal is totally bugged. I need to close the tmux pane in order to fix the terminal. After all this the file will be created and the content will be as expected.
It is obvious something is not right here but I have absolutely no idea why.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713421/why-doesnt-history-vim-work) in StackOverflow but it does not answer mine.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning that happens if `vim` is reading from a pipe. You are basically running `vim someFile`, while reading the empty output of `xargs`. I don't understand why this bugs your terminal though.

Comment: @Panki What exacly do you mean by "while reading the empty output of `xargs`"? As per my understanding `xargs` takes the `stdout` text and converts it to an argument for the `vim` command.

Comment: The reset command will fix the terminal.  You may need to use ctrl-j instead of enter.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up `xargs` and `echo`. `vim` is getting nothing on `stdin` from `echo` because `xargs` is parsing that.

Comment: @Panki Yes, I expact exactly that. I don't understand why `vim fileName` and `echo fileName | xargs vim` behave differently when they need to be do the same thing in a different way. Is that correct or am I missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stty sane` will correct your terminal issue.

The reason this is happening is that `xargs` is not opening your `tty` in the child process.

You need to add the `-o` option in `xargs` for "open tty".

```
echo "sane" | xargs -o stty
```

This runs `stty sane` connected to your terminal. It produces no error.

```
echo "sane" | xargs stty
```

This produces an error on BSD:

> stty: stdin isn't a terminal

and on Linux:

> stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

This worked for me:

```
echo /etc/hosts | xargs -o vim
```

Comment: Hi James, `echo someFileName | xargs -o vim` leads to the following error - `xargs: invalid option -- 'o'`

Comment: It's because I have an older version. I will update now and try again.

Comment: What OS? What version of xargs? What does this say for you:
% `xargs --help| grep tty`
  -o, --open-tty               Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process